# Prove that a inner product is zero

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $\langle, \rangle$ and $||,||$ an inner product and a norm over $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ the inequality
$$
||u||\le ||u+av||
$$
holds. How can I prove that $\langle u,v\rangle=0$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take $a=-1$ and $v=u$, then $||u||\le ||0||=0$. Or is $v$ some fixed vector?

Comment: Both are general. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DietrichBurde I would have assumed that $u$ and $v$ are both fixed at the beginning.  Knowing that $\|u\|\leq \|u+av\|$ for *all* $u,v,a$ the statement is incredibly trivial.  Having been given a specific $u$ and a specific $v$ and being told that for these specific $u,v$ that $\|u\|\leq \|u+av\|$ is true for all $a$ and being asked to show that it follows that for this specific $u,v$ that we have $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$ is a much more interesting problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz My remark was only to ask about the formulation of the question, hoping that it will be made more precise. This hasn't happened so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\langle u,v \rangle \neq 0$. Square both sides of your inequality to get
$$\|u\|^2 \leq \|u\|^2 + 2a\langle u,v \rangle + a^2\|v\|^2$$
or
$$2a\langle u,v \rangle + a^2\|v\|^2 \geq 0$$
for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Choosing $a = -\frac{\langle u,v \rangle}{\|v\|^2}$ yields a contradiction.

Comment: In the first inequality, are you forgetting the $a^2$ term next to $||v||^2$?

Comment: @DiegoVargas Yes, sorry, I corrected it.